# Attempted to Rename Transaction to "..." After Transaction Name Was Already Frozen

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I'm getting the following warning on every request:

> Attempted to rename transaction to Controller/sessions/new after transaction name was already frozen.

I'm running on Cedar on Heroku with `Ruby 2.0.0p195`, `Rails 4.0.0.rc`, `Unicorn 4.6.2` and `RPM 3.6.2.96`. I've traced the exception to the following file (line 108) but I'm unsure of what to do to fix:

https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/master/lib/new_relic/agent/transaction.rb

Comment: I have the exact same issue on actually the exact same setup (but for Heroku EU). Also saw that line in the code even. I could not find a solution yet, I should have posted also to SO before :) I would also post that to New Relic's support (support.newrelic.com), however I opened another ticket with them and it took a week to get an initial response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work at New Relic.

When you get a message like this, it's due to the component of our app known as Real User Monitoring (RUM), which attempts to monitor page load time in the customer's browser.  Why should this affect your ability to rename transactions?  We base the timing capture in the user's browser on the transaction ID--which is tied to transaction name on your server--and this information goes into the footer we've created for your web page.  By the time we create that footer, whatever the transaction name is will continue to be the case through the end of the transaction.  In the case that you have a slow page load that corresponds to a slow app server transaction and we captured both traces, then in our UI you'll be able to click between the two (*This* slow page load came from *that specific* slow transaction).

Rails 4 makes this rather harder if you're using the turbolink feature.  We're working on explicit support for that very soon, but as it stands, turbolinks basically preclude RUM from working after the first page load (if your app has links to itself in it, anyway).

So, your options for fixing it are:

1. rename your transaction earlier in the code sequence--preferably rather far before the end of the content generation (necessarily before  gets output, but in some cases rather sooner)
2. turn off browser monitoring for this app, as you can then rename transactions at any point in the execution

Note that suggestion 1 might not work considering the state of our turbolinks support.  We'll have support for that as soon as we can--certainly sometime this year.  Unfortunately we don't promise timelines, we just deliver features, so I can't be more specific on timing.

Comment: I'm not using turbolinks in the application and furthermore turning off browser monitoring doesn't seem to have helped. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I just got this error, too. We are not using turbolinks, but I see it often in our rails app in our ActiveAdmin pages.